# "Column" cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, variables

i am trying some of the practice New Boston videos and can't get this to work! I am very new to java, this is my first class. I have an assignment to do a 2d array and I can't figure out how to get it to display on the screen. This practice is from Thenewboston's Java tutorials, video # 34 and it works for him!

```
public class inventory {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int firstarray[][]= {{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15}};
    int secondarray[][]={{30,31,32,33},{43},{4,5,6}};

    System.out.println("This is the first array");              
    display(firstarray);
    System.out.println("This is the second array");
    display(secondarray);
    }


public static void display (int x[][])
{
    for(int row=0;row<x.length;row++)
    {
        for(int column=0;column<x.length;column++);
            System.out.print(x[row][column]+"\t");
        }

     { 

    System.out.println();
     }
```

}
}

Comment: Rule no. 1 when learning about some programming lang.: Do not watch thenewboston videos.

Comment: Also, learning to code and Youtube? Maybe I'm just too old, but this doesn't compute to me...

Comment: @ppeterka66 Not old at all. Goo' ol' books are always better.

Comment: Any insight as to why it is printing all the rows on the same line?

Comment: And i have to learn on Youtube because my teacher and my learning style aren't very compatible:(.

Answer (score 6):

You've put a `;` after the for loop, negating what you thought was its body. Get rid of

```
for(int column=0;column<x.length;column++); // <--- this ;
```

In this situation, the body of the `for` loop, where `column` variable is declared and has scope, is everything after the `)` and before the `;`. In other words, nothing. You actually need to replace the `;` with a `{`.

---

Correct indentation would go a long way in helping you write syntactically correct code.

Comment: Seriously, there should be an automatic filter for these mistakes... For the simplest case, even a regex would do :)

Comment: @ppeterka66 In this example, removing the `;` would still not compile, needs to add `{`. Regexes on regexes on regexes.

Comment: But it could have raised a flag :) There could be a button "paste answer for removing semicolon from if/for/while statement", and 3 approves would make it immediately closed...

Comment: @ppeterka66 Oh you mean for the questions. Yeah, but then we wouldn't get the points!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have semicolon at the end of for cycle and not good formating. There are also two brackets, which are absolutely useless :). The right code can look like this :

```
public static void display(int x[][]) {
    for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < x.length; column++) {
            System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Still the display function is not correct, it fails at the end, because the difference of length of rows and columns.

If you want to make this functional, at the second for cycle, you should consider the length of the actual ROW, not how many rows (which is `x.length`).

You only need change `column < x.length` to `column < x[row].length`

So the working code is this :

```
public static void display(int x[][]) {
    for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < x[row].length; column++) {
            System.out.print(x[row][column] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```